# server installed- cannot see any repositorys

Tags: plasticscm

I have downloaded plastic and am trying to set it up locally on my machine.

I have installed it, and setup on localhost.
ive added users, and configured plastic

when i initially logged in using the plastic client i had the default repo, i renamed this to testRepo, and then changed my login to another user, but now cannot see any repo's, i have even changed user back to the original user i used, but still cannot see any repo's.

whats worse is I tried to create a new repo, but it says i dont have permission to mk repo,
so i cant see anything to change the permissions, and i cant create any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you didn´t selected a known user as a repserver owner. In that case, this user will have all the permissions to perform the operations and seeing the repositoies.

So please, after the issue is fixed, configure a repserver owner to avoid future issues.

### Solution 1

**(YOU WILL LOSS THE REPOSITORIES INFORMATION!!!)**

If you are just testing the program and you don´t have information stored in the repositories, you can just delete the files:

```
repositories.plastic
rep_1.plastic
rep_2.plastic
```

and restart the Plastic service.

Now, if you can run the command `cm lrep` the database will be restored and a new `default` repository will be created.

### Solution 2

If you don´t want to lose the repositories content, I would ask you to contact to:  support at codicesoftware dot com

We would need to run some queries to manually modify a couple of database values in order to reset the Plastic permissions in your server.